# parse html tag to be displayed as real html component in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display the

`<br><br><a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'><button>Click me !</button></a>`

as a real HTML component but it keeps showing as a text, I've tried to use a `DomParser` as shown in the below

```js
function test() {
  var str = "<br><br><a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'><button>Click me !</button></a> ";
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  tt.outerHTML = str;
  console.log(doc.body);
  return doc.body;
}
```

but it shows text like this "[object HTMLBodyElement]" and not showing the component!

Comment: Please add `tt` to the snippet I made. If you want to show an HTML string as text, don't use outerHTML but use textContent instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show an HTML string as text, don't use outerHTML but use textContent instead

You EITHER mean

```js
function test() {
  var str = "<br><br><a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'><button>Click me !</button></a> ";
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  console.log(doc.body);
  return doc.body.innerHTML;
}
document.getElementById("tt").textContent = test()
```

```html
<div id="tt"></div>
```

OR if you want to show the button, then you need to copy the innerHTML to innerHTML

```js
function test() {
  var str = "<br><br><a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'><button>Click me !</button></a> ";
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  console.log(doc.body);
  return doc.body.innerHTML;
}
document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = test()
```

```html
<div id="tt"></div>
```

Comment: when i run the page its not showing <a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'><button>Click me !</button></a> as a href its shows as string ! how could it be converted as html component not string !I hope u get my point !